# TestFlight to App Store transition

Tags: ios-appstore, testflight

I just want to know the process from TestFlight to the App Store like

Once my app is visible in the TestFlight of iTunes Connect:

1. When and how will it be moved to the App Store for being LIVE?
2. Apps, once uploaded, are automatically visible in the TestFlight app, when will this be removed: after 180 days, or 90 days, or when the app is live?
3. When does the reviewing process start? The moment app is uploaded to TestFlight, or when it is promoted by someone for LIVE?
4. Who promotes the build for LIVE?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> 1. When and how will it be moved to the App Store for being LIVE?

When the developer is confident the version is ready to go live, he/she just submits the TestFlight build (or a newer one with fixes) like a regular app update. Apple has to review it again (even if you use the same build as for TestFlight) and after approval it will go live.

> 2. Apps, once uploaded, are automatically visible in the TestFlight app, when will this be removed: after 180 days, or 90 days, or when the app is live?

The standard testing period is 90 days, so after that, the app will disappear, but (IIRC) if that version of the app goes live, that ends the availability in TestFlight as well.

> 3. When does the reviewing process start? The moment app is uploaded to TestFlight, or when it is promoted by someone for LIVE?

When the app is uploaded to TestFlight for an alpha test (by users which also have access to the iTunes Connect backend), no review takes place (except for some automated integrity checks). For a beta test via TestFlight, a short (manual) review is conducted by Apple, but nowhere near as rigorous as for an app going live. Again, the "going live"-review is a *separate* review.

> 4. Who promotes the build for LIVE?

This is part of the process described under 1.

Comment: Just one more thing .... does user get an option / button to promote app for submission....i am a tester and couldnt find an option for promoting testflight build to appstore submission..

Comment: No, that's not possible. The developer (or whoever they put in control of their iTunes Connect account) has full control over this.

Comment: Can someone clarify how exactly in the App Store Connect interface you take the build currently in TestFlight and directly submit it to the App Store review process? The only things I can seem to be able to do are add test users and expire the build; we're trying to use the exact version that's up there already and don't want to increment the version number (yet again).